# How to prevent django test runner from flushing db after each test?

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I'm using `pytest-django` plugin for running tests, I need prevent the database from being flushed after each test, which is the default behavior when the tests are defined as below. **Note**: I populate the `User` table before running the tests, that's why the below works.

```
class TestViews:
    @staticmethod
    def test1(django_user_model):
        assert django_user_model.objects.count() > 0

    @staticmethod
    def test2(django_user_model):
        assert django_user_model.objects.count() > 0
```

result:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_live_server.py::TestViews::test1 
test_live_server.py::TestViews::test2 

============================== 2 passed in 7.86s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, when [live_server](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/42b7db2f4f5dbe785e57652d1d4ea9eda39e56e3/pytest_django/fixtures.py#L514) fixture is included:

```
class TestViews:
    @staticmethod
    def test1(django_user_model, live_server):
        assert django_user_model.objects.count() > 0

    @staticmethod
    def test2(django_user_model, live_server):
        assert django_user_model.objects.count() > 0
```

all model tables are flushed after each test.

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_live_server.py::TestViews::test1 
test_live_server.py::TestViews::test2
  
PASSED                             [ 50%]  # records ok
FAILED                             [100%]  # records dropped
tests/test_live_server.py:5 (TestViews.test2)
0 != 0

Expected :0
Actual   :0
<Click to see difference>

django_user_model = <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
live_server = <LiveServer listening at http://localhost:61926>

    @staticmethod
    def test2(django_user_model, live_server):
>       assert django_user_model.objects.count() > 0
E       AssertionError: assert 0 > 0
E        +  where 0 = <bound method BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method of <django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager object at 0x10d83fc90>>()
E        +    where <bound method BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method of <django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager object at 0x10d83fc90>> = <django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager object at 0x10d83fc90>.count
E        +      where <django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager object at 0x10d83fc90> = <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>.objects

test_live_server.py:8: AssertionError

========================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 7.63s ==========================
```

By digging further, I found that [call_command('flush', ...)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0b78ac3fc7bd9f0c57518d0c1a153582318edd59/django/test/testcases.py#L1314) is called after each test, which doesn't happen when `live_server` is not present in the function parameters.

So I tried setting `-reuse-db` or adding it to `pytest.ini`, when I check using `django_db_keepdb`, it evaluates to True when the flag is specified however, the database is flushed anyway. Also `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=true)` is not working.

Comment: I tried both, setting `--reuse-db` as a flag as well as in `pytest.ini`, which sets `django_db_keepdb` to `True` but the database is flushed anyway after the first test, same as shown in the question. Not sure how to mark a whole test class as a transaction, I tried decorating the class and still, the same result.

Comment: Not sure if it is what you want, but you can have a prefilled db data using `fixtures` in your  test cases. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading

Comment: That's similar to what I'm doing using `django_db_setup` and populate the database using a script, which gets flushed after the first test IF `live_server` is used. I want to prevent the database from being flushed whether I'm using `live_server` or not.

Comment: Is including the `django_db_serialized_rollback` fixture sufficient for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, put it in your Django settings file

[image]

I'm sure you can find a way to set it in your test conftest.py file, if you do let me know how, thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).